# check table existence in RDBMS databases

Tags: sql-server, oracle, db2, teradata, rdbms

How to check if a table exists or not in a database like Oracle, Teradata, SQL Server, DB2, etc. in a generic way.

Option 1:

```
Select 1 from Table;
```

Option 2:

```
Describe Table;
```

Which one is better or is there any other better way?

**Edit:** Isn't `select 1 from Table` supported by all these databases & generic way to check existence?

Comment: Have your heard of the term system catalog or data dictionary? Even if you get an error querying the table it might exist, protected from your access.

Comment: `Describe` is certainly **not** a valid option for SQL Server ....

Comment: Describe is a client command in Oracle, so it will work from SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer and maybe others, but not via JDBC; and even in those clients you would need to parse the client output to see if it was there.

Comment: Given the databases you've named, as far as I know there is no generic method to accomplish what you're trying to do using an SQL query. The ANSI-standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is not implemented by all these databases (Oracle being a notable non-implementer; there may be others). Various vendor-neutral database access methods such as ODBC (and JDBC?) implement methods for querying metadata, but not all drivers implement those methods.

Comment: If you are using Java/JDBC you can use `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()` - the driver will then take care of generating the correct query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()` works for all the RDBMS I mentioned ?

Comment: @devツ: yes it does. It is the *most* basic API method in JDBC (and a mandatory one as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: there's **not** a way to accomplish what you are requesting. Different RDBMSs represent schemas, tables, permissions, and data dictionaries in different ways.

Bigger answer: the entity asking the question needs to know what RDBMS it is querying. Then the table existence question can be formed for the database system in question. Even with this information, @data_hinrik is correct, permissions may prevent you from seeing an existing table.

Answer (score 0):

this should works on SQL Server & MySQL

```
select *
from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where   TABLE_NAME =  'Table'
```

Not supported : Oracle

Comment: There is no INFORMATION_SCHEMA in Oracle, at least through 11.1,  unless you've built something like this yourself. In Oracle your best bet is to query USER_TABLES, ALL_TABLES, or DBA_TABLES.

Comment: Really ? I haven't touch Oracle for a long long time ago. i must have been mistaken. But could have sworn i use that on Oracle before. .

Comment: Perhaps they've de-implemented it (which I doubt), but I've checked Oracle databases from 9 through 11.1 - none of them implement `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. All Oracle doc refs which mention INFORMATION_SCHEMA are for MySQL.

Comment: i guess, it must have been a in-house VIEW then.

Answer (score 0):

Generic way using JDBC:

```
Connection conn;
<...connect here...>

try {
  conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from " + table_name + " where 1=0");
} catch (Exeception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: At least add a `where 1 = 0`to the query otherwise the JDBC driver might actually retrieve the 10 million rows in that table.

Comment: not if you start fetching the ResultSet; but yes, better be safe than sorry - I updated it.

Comment: Some JDBC driver already fetch the data when you run executeQuery()

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle there is user_tables view to check all of the tables that exist in the user schema. all_tables view for the tables that exist in a user schema plus the tables which the current user has select rights for the tables for other schemas. dba_tables contains all the tables in the database.

```
select * from user_tables where table_name='YOURTABLENAME';
```